# How can i make automatically models for my http requests

Tags: angular, typescript

For example when i make http request to

https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/passenger?page=0&size=10

there is big NESTED DATA that is returned back.

I have an app where almost every http request is returning a big nested responses. It is time consuming for me to write all of the interfaces manually.

Is there some way with which i can do this automatically ? For example i get the array of objects that is returned by the api and i paste somewhere to give me all models

i tried something like

http://json2ts.com/

but it gives models until first nested objects.After that it does not take the another nested elements.

For example for this

```
"data": [
{
"_id": "5f1c59c8fa523c3aa793bf23",
"name": "Arvind3",
"trips": 1001111,
"airline": [
{
"_id": "5f9b097939f12f6e36b3079a",
"id": 23,
"name": "SerbiaAir",
"country": "Serbia",
"logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/ed/EVA_Air_logo.svg/250px-EVA_Air_logo.svg.png",
"slogan": "Sharing the World, Flying Together",
"head_quaters": "376, Hsin-Nan Rd., Sec. 1, Luzhu, Taoyuan City, Taiwan",
"website": "www.evaair.com",
"established": "1989",
"__v": 0
}
],
"__v": 0
},
```

it gives me

```
    export interface RootObject {
        totalPassengers: number;
        totalPages: number;
        data: Datum[];
    }
```

please tell me some better way which will solve my problem

Comment: Analysis tools most probably won't work for the JSON from the API you've provided because it's inconsistent. For the some of the elements in the `data` array, their `airline` property is an array and for the rest it's an object. Most static analysis tools can't figure it out. If indeed any exists to differentiate the two, I'm unaware of it. Also IMO the JSON is inconsistent and it'll need preprocessing before used.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be looking for something existing rather than a way to make it yourself i'd suggest [transform.tools](https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript)